# Young child wants ID for a plant in his school garden

Tags: identification, lawn, bulbs, native

"B" is 4 years old. That is his hand with the coin for size reference.

Added 2 pics, and info.  Mom said: "The leaves look like grass blades. They're pretty tall and the director said they sprouted up super quickly. They don't smell oniony." They also took a leaf picture, as requested. Thanks all, for your input! :)

My original post:

My friend's young child is wanting an ID on this plant that has sprouted up in his nursery school garden (located in New York City).

His Mom asked me: "Diane can you name that plant? (The one with the white orb with the green shoot sticking out of it) They sprouted up on their own at B's school garden and no one can identify it."

So...I could probably eventually ID this one for him. (I figure that it is in the onion/scallion family.) But, we would rather include the kid in this, for his school project. His Mom can read him your questions, clarification requests, and answers. I will pass on more pictures and info as it is supplied to me. (I am in Virginia, not on location in NY.)

This should be a nice switch for everyone after the difficult ID's that I have asked for in the past. Please play along. Thanks! :D

Garden location NYC, NY. USA

[image: B's mystery plant][! [[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxYWJ.jpg)[B's mystery plant][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bX4X.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bX4X.jpg) [image]

Comment: I would like a close-up to the inflorescence.

Comment: Leek, onion or garlic, not sure which, the flowers look very round, but all three are capable of producing scapes. Dig one up to see what's at the bottom...

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi- I will ask for more pictures

Comment: @Bamboo- Thanks. I'm sure that the kids will be happy to have an excuse to dig one up! :D

Comment: Don't know the "scientific" name, but the common name has got to be "marshmallow on a stick". ...  Is this supposed to be an easy ID task? I never saw a plant like that. People keep mentioning aliums, leeks, onions, etc. but I never saw one that had the top of the stem poking out of the flower ball like that. I.e. looking like an *impaled* marshmallow, rather than a marshmallow sitting *on top of* the skewer. Cattails look like that, but I never saw a white one of those either.

Comment: lol @LorelC. - Gosh. I actually thought this one would be easy. Instead, here I go posting another one to keep everyone up nights, again. If nobody can solve it, I'll bet that the little kids would be happy to call it "Marshmallow on a Stick". ;) My friend is going to try to get more info about it from the director (and take more pics) when she picks her kid up from school today.

Comment: @LorelC. - leeks onions and garlic are all capable of producing these - one example here for garlic, though the flowers  are not open, and note, the scapes are much prized for eating, especially on onions, but cut before the flowers open up https://ediblesanmarcos.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/garlic-scapes-is-the-spring-need-removing/

Comment: @Bamboo- Your link has useful info. Thank you!

Comment: @Bamboo, oho! Thanks! Another case of: I don't see correctly what I'm looking at, because I already think I know what it is.  ....But I still can't figure out what this plant is.

Answer (score 3):

Expert botanic uses many senses to identify a plant, but they know the dangers of plants.

For such plant, a simple touch will tell you (by smelling the air or the hand) if is a garlic species (*Alium sp.*).  But I don't recommend people to touch plants they don't know. Some are poisonous at minimal contact.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer because a longer one isn't needed. Answering on my phone so  limited in formatting the link.
I believe it to be Egyptian walking onion.

[Egyptian Walking Onion](http://www.burpee.com/vegetables/onions/onion-egyptian-walking-onion-prod002386.html)